# Simulink errors when trying to simulate design

Tags: matlab, simulink, xilinx

I am trying to simulate a design in MATLAB/Simulink and for whatever reason I am getting errors preventing me from simulating the design. I have taken screenshots showing the design and the error messages, thanks in advance for any help ???

[image]

[image]

If you need any more information, please ask ... :)

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that the images are hard to read, but opening them in a new tab should help ...

Comment: Did you open that log file, which the error message is talking about in H:\ ?

Comment: Yes but nothing useful i can post it if you like

Comment: Sure, if its nothing useful, complain the s-function developer, it doesn't appear to be a standard block